# Dynamic query to obtain dynamic list from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Actually, My project have a Entity Framework and i have a list of tables each one have different columns like one table have 3 columns and another one have 10 columns. When ever i send table name to query need to get values from database as dynamically. I have used below method to get values as dynamic,

```
public dynamic GetTableValuesUsingAnalysisData(AnalysisQueries queryName)
{
      dynamic result = null;
      try
      {
           using (var cases = new ApiRassiEntities())
           {
                 result = cases.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(sqlQuery).ToList();
           }      
      }   
      return result;
}

 public class AnalysisQueries
 {
        public string QueryName { get; set; }
 }
```

Above method is working correctly but the results showed as object in attached image.

[image]

I have tried lot of links but nothing helped me. Please give your suggestion.

Thanks..

Comment: *Above method is working correctly* According to the results, apparently not :) You can't use `dynamic` as generic argument to `SqlQuery`, EF works only with static types.

Comment: Why would you even want to use an ORM for dynamic tables?

Comment: Any other way to get table values  as dynamic?@IvanStoev

Comment: In general no. If you know somehow the type `T` representing the query result, then the `SqlQuery` method can be called via reflection. If you don't have a class representing the query result, you should use some other (micro) ORM like Dapper etc.